# How to set language other than English as the development language and Base localization?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization, internationalization

When an Xcode project of iOS app is newly created, in the project (not target) setting we can see that it has `Use Base internationalization` enabled by default, and there are 2 files localized for the `Development Language` which is `English` by default (one for `Main.storyboard` and one for `LaunchScreen.storyboard`, both of which reside in the `Base.lproj` directory).  See below the screenshot:

[image: Xcode default project localization setting]

(For simplicity, I will only mention `Main.storyboard` from now on.)

And in the localization section of `Main.storyboard`'s right-side panel, we can see that the `Base` localization is checked by default and there is also an `English` localization which is unchecked by default.  See below the screenshot:

[image: storyboard default localization setting]

And in the target's `Info.plist`, there is a key named `Localization native development region` (i.e. `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion`), and its default value is `en`.  See below the screen shot:

[image: Localization native development region]

If I understand it correctly, with these default settings, developer can just write English in the `Base` localization of `Main.storyboard` and leave the `English` localization as unchecked.  If the app needs to adapt to some other language, developer can add a localization in the project localization setting, and select `Main.storyboard` in the popped up dialog.  See below the screenshot:

[image: add localization]

Take `Chinese (Simplified)` as an example, this will result in a newly created directory `zh-Hans.lproj` with a `Main.strings` file inside it.  (For simplicity, I will refer to it as `Chinese` instead of `Chinese (Simplified)`.)  Developer just needs to translate the English strings inside this file into Chinese (the newly created `Main.strings` in the `zh-Hans.lproj` directory by default has all the English texts duplicated from the `Main.storyboard` in `Base.lproj`).  With these settings, the `Language` field in the description of this app on AppStore will list English (from the `Base` localization, because English is the `development language`) and Chinese (from the `Chinese` localization).  On end-user's device, if the system language is English/Chinese (or English/Chinese is among the preferred language), the app will use the corresponding language resource (for English, use the `Base` localization; for Chinese, use the `Chinese` localization).  For all other language preference, English will act as the fallback language because `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` is `en`, so `Base` localization is used.

So my first question will be, is the above understanding correct?  To summarize, with the `development language` being English, we don't need to enable `English` localization for storyboard files.  Just use the `Base` localization and directly write English in the storyboard files.  We only need to add localization for languages other than English.  (Actually it seems troublesome if we enable the `English` localization.  If `English` localization is enabled, then we need to maintain both the texts in `Base.lproj/Main.storyboard` and `en.lproj/Main.strings`.)

If the above understanding is correct, my second question will be, how to achieve internationalization in a reverse way?  That is to say, if I would like to use `Chinese` as the `development language` and write Chinese in the `Base` localization, and only add localization for languages other than `Chinese`, is it possible and how to do that in Xcode?  I can't find a way to change the `development language` in the project setting in order to claim that the `Base` localization in the project is `Chinese` rather than `English`.

Comment: This means that you have Base(English) and Chinese language. If you want to translate them, you must set texts in both language strings. If language is changed from settings, the app will set translated string. If you want to set language from your app(locale) you can use LocalizationSystem. https://github.com/rudensm/LocalizationSystem

Comment: please don't set the language from your app. you're just asking for bugs and a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your understanding is mostly correct. One small clarification: if the user is running in some third language, like Russian, it is not necessarily true that the app will run in English. Instead, the app will run in the first language it supports that the user prefers. As of iOS 8 and later, users can have a *list* of preferred languages, such as "Russian, French, Chinese, English". In the case of this hypothetical user, the app would actually run in Chinese, since it is earlier in the list than English.

To answer your question regarding changing the development language, this isn't straightforward to do but can be done. Specifically:

1. Add the language you want to be your Base language first. **Uncheck** all of the files that Xcode offers to localize for you.
2. In the `Info.plist` (as you observed), change the development region to the language that you want to be your base language. Note that the property is a bit misnamed, because its value should be a **language code** (with an optional country code), rather than a region or country code.
3. Close your project in Xcode. In another code editor, open `projectname.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` and search for `developmentRegion`. You should see a line like `developmentRegion = English;`. Change this to reference the same language you put in your `Info.plist` file.
4. Reopen the project in Xcode. Go through all your localizable files and check the boxes next to English to generate the localizable resources. Note that for storyboards and xibs, Xcode might create a storyboard instead of a strings file. If that happens, just change the filetype to strings file.

Here's an example of the result for me using `fr` as the Base language:

[image: Project info]

[image: File info]

Comment: I didn't had the option to Uncheck all pf the files that xcode offer me. 
So I left the lunch screen, and after I finished the process I just want to the lunch screen and uncheck the file from the right side menu.

Comment: At what point did you add your second language (English) and how did you manage to get rid of "Base" in your first screenshot ("Localizations"), even with "Use Base Internationalization" ticked? I followed the steps but I had to select one of the files, otherwise Xcode didn't add the new language, so I left "LaunchScreen" as Idan suggested. I changed the development language as you described, which didn't get rid of "Base". Unticking it for the storyboards asks me if I want to move and replace it and then I get an error ("doesn't contain valid data for UTF-16 encoding").

Comment: Btw, changing the "developmentRegion" in the file also creates a new list entry in "Localizations" with "0 Files Localized".